# Turn off helm-descbinds in spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs, kubernetes-helm

How can i turn off helm-descbinds so that describe-bindings executes the old describe-bindings? (helm-descbinds-mode nil) doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

(advice-remove 'describe-bindings #'helm-descbinds)

Answer (score 0):

### [Solved for spacemacs]

I have utilized this with GNU Emacs version 30.0.50, and the outcome is that I can use which-key once again as it was automatically disabled when helm-descbinds-mode is turned on.

> (helm-descbinds-mode 0)

In spacmeacs I put this command in the user-config with my other configurations.

```
(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
          (helm-descbinds-mode 0) 
)
```